# Index of a subgroup in a matrix group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of all $2\times 2$ matrices with integer entries and let $H$ be the subgroup of all $2\times 2$ matrices with even integer entries. Then I want to find the index of $H$ in $G$.

I think it is $16$. As all cosets will be of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&b \\ c& d\end{pmatrix}+H$. Now we can choose $16$ such matrices. Am I right?

Comment: why $16$?? you might want to share your thoughts... What do you say?

Comment: I think each place in the matrix can be chosen by 0 or 1. But I am not sure.

Comment: Since you have a "group of matrices with integer entries", would your group _operation_ be addition?

Comment: yes, $G$ is an additive group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact sequence $0\to 2\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\diagup 2\mathbb Z\to 0$ gives rise to the exact sequence:
$$0\to\text{Mat}(2,2\mathbb Z)\to\text{Mat}(2,\mathbb Z)\to\text{Mat}(2,\mathbb Z\diagup 2\mathbb Z)\to 0.$$

Thus:
$$|\text{Mat}(2,\mathbb Z):\text{Mat}(2,2\mathbb Z)|=|\text{Mat}(2,\mathbb Z\diagup 2\mathbb Z)|=|\mathbb Z\diagup 2\mathbb Z|^4=16.$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right. We can choose these representativesof cosets:$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a& b\\c& d\end{array}\right), a,b,c,d\in\{0,1\}$. Then each element $g\in G$ is equal to $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a& b\\c& d\end{array}\right)+h$ for some element $h\in H$, there entrie of $\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a& b\\c& d\end{array}\right)$ is $0$ if corresponding entrie in $g$ is even and odd, otherwise.